# How do I get Xcode to let me create a Carbon Unit Test Bundle target?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, unit-testing, macos-carbon

I am having trouble creating a unit test in an Xcode project.  The project was created from a template for a 'command-line tool that links against the stdc++ library'.

Apple's instructions for creating a unit test say to set the desired target type for a C++ program, I should use the New Target Assistant and 'select the Carbon > Unit Test Bundle target'.

But my Xcode is not giving me the option to select Carbon.

I am using Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/CPlusTestReference/index.html talks about the CPlusTest framework and mentions in particular the directory /System/Library/Frameworks/CPlusTest.framework.  I've just run the Xcode installer again and made sure every option was selected.  The directory is still not present on my machine.  Apple's developer web has not revealed to me where I might download something that might install the framework.